# DirectoryEntry refresh misc probleme

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

In code, I move a computer account in an other active directory OU using this code.

```
DirectoryEntry eLocation = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + DevicePath, ADAdmin, ADPass);
DirectoryEntry nLocation = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ADMoveOU, ADAdmin, ADPass);

eLocation.MoveTo(nLocation);
eLocation.CommitChanges();
eLocation.RefreshCache();
nLocation.Close();
eLocation.Close();
```

From here code return everything good computer moved to an other OU. But, I need refresh data for user now using this code.

```
DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry(Domain, ADUSER, ADpassword);
Entry.RefreshCache();
DirectorySearcher Search = new DirectorySearcher(Entry);
Search.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn={0}))", DeviceName);
```

And here is the problem this chunk of code tell me computer not moved
in reality I have to wait like 30 second between move and refresh for get the correct active directory data.

So, I don't get whats up. I even refresh cache so why the move result isn't refresh right after move?.

Comment: There may be 2 reasons causing this issue: UsePropertyCashe property of DirectoryEntry is set to true. Should be set to false. The other reason is when you make change on one domain controller and connecting to some other. In this case you have to wait for replication to pass. Always connect to the same DC in multi DC environment

Comment: i tryed everything i can on cashe . so i guess its delay from controler but not sure how to set a code to deall with this

Comment: Pass a domain controller name to DirectoryEntry constructor, e. g. LDAP://mydomaincontroller.mydomain.com. You can get a valid working DC by calling DomainController.FindOne method

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this myself now - from what I can tell it seems like Active Directory itself takes some time to process moving an object from one container/OU to another - the change appears to persist on the Active Directory server itself for at least several seconds.

One work around would be to add a custom field to the objects that indicates where it is stored - and then use that to build your query.